# d3.js v3 to v4 errors - animation and textcontext

Tags: node.js, reactjs, d3.js

I am refactoring a chart application from v3 to v4

1. "TypeError: callback.call is not a function"

here is the code -- but I am not sure why this is causing an callback.call error?

```
waveGroup.attr('transform','translate('+waveGroupXPosition+','+waveRiseScale(0)+')')
```

[image]

---

I believe its an issue with this animateWave code

```
            // Data for building the clip wave area.
            var data = [];
            for(var i = 0; i <= 40*waveClipCount; i++){
                data.push({x: i/(40*waveClipCount), y: (i/(40))});
            }
var clipArea = d3.area()

        var wave = waveGroup.append("path")
            .datum(data)
            .attr("d", clipArea)
            .attr("T", 0);


        function animateWave() {
            wave.attr('transform','translate('+waveAnimateScale(wave.attr('T'))+',0)');

            wave.transition()
                .duration(config.waveAnimateTime * (1-wave.attr('T')))
                .ease('linear')
                .attr('transform','translate('+waveAnimateScale(1)+',0)')
                .attr('T', 1)
                .each('end', function(){
                    wave.attr('T', 0);
                    animateWave(config.waveAnimateTime);
                });
        }
```

and I think I need to refactor it -- so its more like this

```
function repeat() {
  timeCircle
    .attr('cx', 210)          // position the circle at 40 on the x axis
    .attr('cy', (yPos*45)+25) // position the circle at 250 on the y axis
    .transition()             // apply a transition
    .ease(easement)           // control the speed of the transition
    .duration(4000)           // apply it over 2000 milliseconds
    .attr('cx', 720)          // move the circle to 920 on the x axis
    .transition()             // apply a transition
    .ease(easement)           // control the speed of the transition
    .duration(4000)           // apply it over 2000 milliseconds
    .attr('cx', 210)          // return the circle to 40 on the x axis
    .on("end", repeat);       // when the transition finishes start again
};
```

https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/1ea51d03775b9650e8dfd03474e202fe
the easing functions have changed?

Answer (score -2):

I don't see anything wrong with that particular line of code, but I wonder if the error is with the value of `waveGroup`. In d3 it's sometimes easy to confuse which methods return a selection and which do not. My guess is `waveGroup` does not refer to a selection at runtime.